# How to measure Maximum achievable throughput of an SSL connection?

Tags: c, ssl, tcp, openssl, throughput

For my current project I have to measure the throughput of a SSL connection in bytes/second. I cant find a standard way of doing this. Please help me out.

Note: Project development in C.

Comment: If you are able to read and understand source code [ssldump](http://www.rtfm.com/ssldump/), there you go, if not, begin with [SSL_library_init](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]SSL_library_init%28%29)

Comment: Transmit some number of bytes and measure the seconds. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: While measuring maximum achievable TCP throughput, We can send data of size greater than window size and measure the TX rate.Similarly, for SSL connections is there any standard procedure to measure the throughput ?

Comment: So do the same thing. There's no difference. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: I want to measure the maximum achievable SSL connection throughput. For that what is the data size of packets I have to push into the SSL_write call . (in TCP we can push data of size equal to window size to full the buffer). As SSL involves its own overhead and encryption padding and its own protocol packet exchanges, How to measure the "Maximum achivable throughput" ?

Comment: It is exactly the same. There is no difference. You don't need to know any of this. Just write a maximal piece of data and measure the transmit time.

Comment: The Maximum piece of data size will be TCP window size / Maximum SSL record size (16k) ? As per my assumption it should be maximum SSL record size. Is it correct? I just want a standard reference so that I can argue to others confidently. As of now I am pushing data equals to SSL Maximum record size.But the performance is better while I am pushing data of size 6k using SSL_write call compared to 16k data ( Max SSL record size) !!!

Comment: [Nginx Performance Tuning for SSL](http://techsamurais.com/?p=1384) and [Optimizing NGINX TLS Time To First Byte (TTTFB)](https://www.igvita.com/2013/12/16/optimizing-nginx-tls-time-to-first-byte/). Both articles discuss their test rigs and how they are performing measurements.